# unable to bind the css class in template using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to call a css class in one of the span tag that is within a template and it doesn't seem to work

Here is my viewmodel:

```
var data = [
    {
     'id': '1',
     'firstName': 'Megan',
     'lastName': 'Fox',
     'picture': 'images/01.jpg',
     'bio': 'Megan Denise Fox w' 
    },
    {
     'id': '1',
     'firstName': 'asdf',
     'lastName': 'asdf123',
     'picture': 'images/02.jpg',
     'bio': 'hwkhjkds lkawhkhkbs iklhskjha' 
    }
];

var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray(data),
    myClass: ko.observable('test')
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And this is my view:

```
<h1>Profile Viewer</h1>
<div id="profilesTabViewer">
    <ul id="profileTab" data-bind="template: { name: 'profileListTemplate', 
                                               foreach: people }">
    </ul>        
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="profileListTemplate">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: firstName, css: myClass"></span>            
    </li>
</script>
```

I have shared the code in http://jsfiddle.net/du3QX/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in `myClass` binding.

The ViewModel that is binded to your template is an object of `people` not the root/parent ViewModel, for example in first loop it 'll be

```
{
    'id': '1',
    'firstName': 'Megan',
    'lastName': 'Fox',
    'picture': 'images/01.jpg',
    'bio': 'Megan Denise Fox w'
}
```

Now you see it has no such property called `myClass`(it only exist in the root/parent ViewModel).

So, you need to change your binding in `profileListTemplate` template to be like this:

`<span data-bind="text: firstName, css: $parent.myClass"></span>`

OR

`<span data-bind="text: firstName, css: $root.myClass"></span>`

Comment: Thanks Ebram, I'm still not bale to bind my css class. In my application its under a folder css and when I try to use the css class binding the changes are not getting reflected on to my html page. I used both parent and root.

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is not correct. Your are traing to use `myClass` property, which should be an item in `people` observable array. But, according your view model, `myClass` is a property of root viewModel:

So you should add `$root` or `$parent` context (in your case can be used any) in your binding:

```
<span data-bind="text: firstName, css: $root.myClass"></span>
```

**Update**

I changed your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/du3QX/36/), it works correct.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I'm still not bale to bind my css class. In my application its under a folder css and when I try to use the css class binding the changes are not getting reflected on to my html page. I used both parent and root

Comment: @Vimal, check demo, please.